# Isotope plugin layout with justify

Tags: jquery-isotope

I need make nice layout from blocks with 3 width - 20%, 40% and 60%
See example     [`here`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dysfa)
My goal is sort all blocks with alignment on both sides - left and rights...
But now I can see strange - http://s28.postimg.org/5m84du3pp/isotope_problem.jpg:

Answer (score 0):

I Guess that found solution - packery layout...
And everything looks - [`fine`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BaDKi)